# Google Webmaster Highlight Data for paginated blog entries

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, pagination

I'm trying to get google to recognise my entries as articles using the "Start Highlighting" tool in the Webmasters Toolkit. Problem is that if I put a page set "...blog/*/*/" it says, "Pattern does not include start page.", but if I do "...blog/*/" it works.

My blog entries are structured like this: ...blog/[entry-slug]. However, with pagination, page 2 would look like this: ...blog/page/2. And I think google's getting confused.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Obviously, the landing page of my blog does not have ALL entries on show, so google only picks up the 5 on the first page.

Comment: Sorry but this is a little confusing, are you attempting to use PHP? Since only HTML is supported by the Highlight data

Comment: Do you mean `blog/*/*/` (as in the source) or `blog///` (as interpreted by Markdown here)? You can [edit] your question and use code markup (with backticks: `) to make this clear.

Comment: @unor yes, I mean blog/\*/\*/